# Potential leak of an object allocated

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

after **Analyze** my cocos2d game I've got an warning "Potential leak of an object allocated on line 525 and stored into 'valueString'" in this code

```
525  NSString * valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",kGameTimeeng,[allFunctions getTimeFormat:(int) _timeLimit]]] retain];

    if([_language isEqualToString:@"rus"]){
        [valueString release];
        valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",kGameTimerus,[allFunctions getTimeFormat:(int) _timeLimit]]] retain];
    }    

    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)color],
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelValue:withValue:) data:(NSString*)valueString],
                // [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelStroke:withTag:) data:(void*)TagCurentPointsLabelStroke],
                 [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5f blinks:2],
                 [CCShow action], 
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)colorAfter],

                 nil];

    [_timeLimitLabel runAction:sequence];
    [valueString release];
```

allFunctions.m

```
-(void) setLabelValue:(id) sender withValue:(NSString*) value
{   
    CCLabelTTF *label=(CCLabelTTF *)sender;
    NSString * valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value]] autorelease];
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",valueString]];
   //[valueString release];
}
```

can you explain me why?

Comment: In allFunctions.m you should relese the string. However, in these cases I would aurorelease the string. Use autorelease instead of release and do not release it. Additionally (but shoudl not be related to the warning) I would move line 535 into an else branch of the if ... rus statement.

Comment: Sorry, in allFunctions.m you autoreleased it already. I have overlooked that. That is ok as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
valueString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",kGameTimerus,[allFunctions getTimeFormat:(int) _timeLimit]]] retain];
```

You retained twice here: alloc & retain. And then you only release once:

```
[valueString release];
```

That's why there's a potential leak (actually, it's a leak).

And for

```
NSString * valueString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value]] autorelease];
```

you retain once (alloc), and release (`autorelease`) when `valueString` is not needed anymore. This is okay.

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov u'r welcome! Btw, you can try to use [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you're not familiar with memory management. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
525 if([_language isEqualToString:@"rus"]){
        [valueString release];
        valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",kGameTimerus,[allFunctions getTimeFormat:(int) _timeLimit]]] autorelease];
    } else {    
        NSString * valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",kGameTimeeng,[allFunctions getTimeFormat:(int) _timeLimit]]] autorelease];
    }


    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)color],
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelValue:withValue:) data:(NSString*)valueString],
                // [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelStroke:withTag:) data:(void*)TagCurentPointsLabelStroke],
                 [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5f blinks:2],
                 [CCShow action], 
                 [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: allFunctions selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)colorAfter],

                 nil];

    [_timeLimitLabel runAction:sequence];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you alloc init an object that object already has the retain count set to 1, so you don't usually need to retain it. When you release it at the end of your first code example (`[valueString release];`) it will have the retain count to 1, because you retained it after init alloc.

I'm not sure how `CCSequence` and `CCCallFuncND` handles the parameters regarding memory management, but you should be safe if you remove the retain from the indicated line.

Hope this helps.